# Django Channels: How to flush send buffer

Tags: django, websocket, channel

I'm using Django 1.10 with Channels as a backend for an app I'm building.
I've set up websocket communication between my client (Angular 4) and Django. Everything works, but I'm a bit confused.

Consider the following code:

```
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    for a in range(10):
        message.reply_channel.send({'text': json.dumps({'test': '123'})})
        time.sleep(1)
```

Im receiving the respons on the client *after* the for-loop has completed iterations, in this example after 10 seconds.

**Question:** Is it possible to flush the `send` 'buffer', meaning the `message.reply_channel.send` function will send immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instant reply set `immediately=True`:

```
message.reply_channel.send({'text': json.dumps({'Hejsa!!': 'hihi'})}, immediately=True)
```